# GlideException: Failed to load resource

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I encountered the following problem:

> 2022-02-05 20:42:45.442 14841-14841/com.example.zelenin W/Glide: Load failed for "https://static.devli.ru/public/images/gifs/201401/f17e44ad-497d-434a-bc9b-613f2f1be379.gif" with size [1058x1048]
> class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
> Program code:

```
package com.example.zelenin.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.zelenin.R
import com.example.zelenin.databinding.FragmentDevelopersLifeBinding
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL
import kotlin.concurrent.thread


class DevelopersLifeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_developers_life) {
    //var latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    lateinit var binding: FragmentDevelopersLifeBinding
    private var link: String? = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentDevelopersLifeBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //latch.await()
        getUrl()
        binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener() {
            getUrl()
            Glide
                .with(this)
                .asGif()
                .load(link)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(binding.imgGIF)
        }
    }

    private fun asyncActions(str: String?):String?{

        return link
    }

    private fun getUrl(){
        val a = thread{

            val url: URL = URL("https://developerslife.ru/random?json=true")
            val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            try {
                var inputStream = BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.inputStream)
                link = readStream(inputStream)
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect()
            }
            link = crutchDontSee(link)
            Log.d("Hello", link!!)
            //latch.countDown()
        }

    }

    private fun readStream(`is`: InputStream): String? {
        return try {
            val bo = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            var i = `is`.read()
            while (i != -1) {
                bo.write(i)
                i = `is`.read()
            }
            bo.toString()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
             ""
        }
    }
     fun crutchDontSee(param:String?):String?{
       var httpsToHttps = param
        httpsToHttps = httpsToHttps?.substringAfter("\"gifURL\":")
        httpsToHttps = httpsToHttps?.substringBefore(",")
        httpsToHttps = "\"https" + httpsToHttps?.substringAfter("http")
        return httpsToHttps
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
    }



    companion object {
        const val TAG = "DEVELOPERS_LIFE_FRAGMENT"

    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
}}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {

    compileSdk 31
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zelenin"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.12.0"
}
```

All Error:

```
2022-02-06 01:02:58.778 516-1989/? I/system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
2022-02-06 01:02:58.778 516-1989/? I/system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
2022-02-06 01:02:58.783 214-217/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2022-02-06 01:02:58.779 214-214/? W/Binder:214_2: type=1400 audit(0.0:1139): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup34" dev="sysfs" ino=18754 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2022-02-06 01:02:58.786 214-217/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2022-02-06 01:02:58.783 214-214/? W/Binder:214_2: type=1400 audit(0.0:1140): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup35" dev="sysfs" ino=18817 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2022-02-06 01:02:58.794 19626-19626/com.example.zelenin W/Glide: Load failed for "https://static.devli.ru/public/images/gifs/201303/a8288b73-cca0-4886-b646-46ee73ead7cc.gif" with size [1058x1048]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
2022-02-06 01:02:58.912 516-1999/? I/system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
2022-02-06 01:02:58.968 19626-19705/com.example.zelenin D/Hello: "https://static.devli.ru/public/images/gifs/201307/f835354a-c727-418c-a0d7-3eba3b65f67f.gif"
2022-02-06 01:03:01.878 516-1999/? I/system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try the gif link and got a error:  `java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to static.devli.ru not permitted`.   Then I add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`  to the `<application>` label of the manifest file,  now it's OK.

Other solutions: [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: I added this line, also added permissions to use the internet, but it still doesn't work(

Comment: Please paste all the error infomation.

Comment: Probably added)

Comment: Try load a non-gif picture, like https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562155847-c05f7386b204?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8bmV3JTIwd2FsbHBhcGVyfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80

Comment: The problem is that if we pass the url directly to the load method, everything is fine, but if we use an http request to get the string, process it, even if we get the same string, it won't work, I don't understand why

Comment: Hello: "https://static.devli.ru/public/images/gifs/201307/f835354a-c727-418c-a0d7-3eba3b65f67f.gif"    ->  It seems like the "link" variable has quotation marks.

Comment: Now a new problem, the image is not loaded at startup the application and sometimes through a query gets the following output string: 2022-02-06 01:27:49.318 21204-21284/com.example.zelenin D/Hello: https{id:11535

Comment: You'd better use Gson or other json library to parse json string to java object. "substring" may not be reliable.

Comment: Now I do this: processedDescription = jsonObject.getString("description")